# Changing lots of file names in windows

Tags: windows, rename

I have *1900 files* that I'd like to edit their name. The files contain the title of the file but also have unneeded characters that I'd like to remove. For example, one file might be titled `Hello [U].txt`.

Another might be `Bye [U].txt`. Is there a program that can remove that `[U]`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this program ([`Bulk Rename Utility`](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php)) can help you.

See:

1. [image]
2. [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
dir |
Where-Object { $_.name.Contains("[U]") } |
RenameItem -NewName { $_.name -replace "[U]","" }
```

give this a shot written for powershell

Comment: I'll try this next time I need to do it. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander has ability to do that: select the files, press Ctrl+M and you should be able to change names of many files in the way you need.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use the rename utility posted above